# Setting up a domain with a dedicated server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server with a bunch of stuff on it already. Basically, I am accessing it now with the free domain I got when I purchased the server (http://example.com/directory, etc).

I also have a second domain I want to use with a specific subdirectory (http://exampletwo.com/ should basically work as if I were under http://example.com/two, but it should use the exampletwo domain.

I would assume I would change the A record of the second domain to the IP of the server, but how do I make it work with a subdirectory? I have full DNS control of the second domain but it is purchased on from a different registrar than the dedicated server.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Is this "dedicated server" a VPS that is hosted in the cloud somewhere? Are you using Windows/IIS, Linux/Apache, or something else? Ask an absurdly general question and you are likely to get an absurdly general answer.

Comment: @Miles I agree about needing what OS it is running, but I don't see the need for if it's a VPS or Dedicated.

Comment: I also agree that we need to know which OS or at the very least which web server you're running.

Comment: Often, a VPS will come preinstalled with management tools, e.g. Webmin/Virtualmin or WHM/Cpanel. Understanding the specific nature of the server or VPS would enable us to identify the simplest solution.

Comment: @Miles that is very true; I didn't think about that.

Comment: It has Plesk/Virtuozzo and runs CentOS5. Looks like the virtual host thing will work, so looking at that now... I could edit it manually unless Plesk has some sort of way of modifying the file.

Comment: Never mind, looks like Plesk allows you to create new hosting accounts. I just made one and changed the A record to my server IP and it worked perfectly! Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Andrew You are welcome to post an answer to your own question explaining the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I make it work with a subdirectory?

Use [HTTP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)/[rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Settings depend on the web-server.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since my original question did not assume that I had Plesk or other management software available.